# WCF and WebGet - Error when requesting files with extension

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

I have configured a simple method in my service that just sends back what you requested :

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{fileName}")]
[OperationContract]
string GetFile(string fileName);
```

And when I access this method via:
http://localhost:8460/WCFService1/Service.svc/fileName
I get a respond containg the string "fileName".
But I want to be able to accept a request for a file with it's suffix like this :
http://localhost:8460/WCFService1/Service.svc/fileName.jpg
In this case I get an error :
The resource cannot be found
(As if the request was not channeled to the GetFile() method).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug with the asp development server.
When I host the service in webmatrix(IIS express) it works fine and requests made with extensions are ok.